# how to convert an array to an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this code

```
var sourceData = somesourceData;

sourceData.forEach(function (sourceRow) {

   var dataRow = [];

   dataRow.push(sourceRow.desc);

   bodyQData.push(dataRow);

 });
```

which produces this outcome

```
["desc1", "desc2", "etc"]
```

I am trying to get this outcome

```
[
  {text: "desc1", style:"style1"},
  {text: "desc2", style:"style1"},
  {text: "etc", style:"style1"}
]
```

any idea how i can do this.

Comment: `push({text: "what", style: "ever"});`

Comment: ahhhh  so simple. nice Will.  thanx to all who answered.

Comment: @user2062455 Your welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [JavaScript Array map() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) :

```
var arrOfObj =  array.map(function(item, index) {
    return {text: item, style:"style1"};
});
```

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map`

```
var rows = sourceData.map(function(s) {
    return { text: s.desc, style: "style1" }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataRow = [];
somesourceData.forEach(function (sourceRow) {
   dataRow.push({text:sourceRow.desc, style:"style1"});
 });

console.log(dataRow);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an object out of each `sourceRow`, then push it to an array, thus getting an array of objects.

```js
var sourceData = somesourceData;

sourceData.forEach(function(sourceRow) {

  var dataRow = [];

  dataRow = {
    text: sourceRow.desc.text,
    style: sourceRow.desc.text  
  }

  bodyQData.push(dataRow);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your pushing sourceRow.desc into array which is a string i believe

Try the below code

```
var sourceData = somesourceData;

sourceData.forEach(function (sourceRow) {

   var dataRow = [];

   dataRow.push({text:sourceRow.desc, style:"style1"});

   bodyQData.push(dataRow);

 });
```